# Is it okay to add a headline inside an HTML button?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I was wondering if it is semantically correct or OK to add a headline such as h1, h2, h3, h4 inside an HTML button.

**Example**

```
<button type="button">
   <h3>Button headline text</h3>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Semantically? *Maybe*. You could make arguments either way and it would depend on context.

However, syntactically, it is invalid. HTML does not allow `h3` elements to be descendants of `button` elements.